# D3 tree resize SVG in Angular

Tags: angular, d3.js

I am struggling to figure out how to resize an svg in an Angular D3 implementation. I want to resize the svg using the following function, however, the svg is not updated. If i remove the SVG then re-add it, it just disappears completely. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
const resize = (incremement) => {
            this.height += incremement;
            const height = this.height - this.margin.top - this.margin.bottom;

            const element = this.chartContainer.nativeElement;

            this.tree = d3.layout.tree().size([(height), this.width]);

            // this line removes the svg but it is never re-added. 
            // d3.select(element).remove('svg'); 

            this.svg = d3.select(element).append('svg')
                .attr('width', this.width + this.margin.right + this.margin.left)
                .attr('style', 'border: 1px solid black;')
                .attr('height', height + this.margin.top + this.margin.bottom)
                .append('g')
                .attr('transform', 'translate(' + this.margin.left + ',' + this.margin.top + ')');
            update(this.root);
        };
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The solution was very simple...

```
const resize = (incremement) => {

            this.height = incremement;
            const height = this.height - this.margin.top - this.margin.bottom;

            this.tree = d3.layout.tree().size([(height), this.width]);

            const chart = document.querySelector('#svgChart');
            chart.setAttribute('height', this.height.toString());

            update(this.root);
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue with D3Plus, it worked by regenerating the resize event again, not sure in you case.. it is required to remove the old one ? Below is the code ! hope it help.

```
window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
```